# Applying a mathematical function to another mathematical function

Tags: mysql

I've been asked write a statement that does the following: "increase the money by power 2 then divide it by 2. Round the results to whole numbers".

This is the [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1zQU.png)

This is what I've got so far

```
SELECT event_id, place, money, 
POWER(money,2)/2 as x,
ROUND(x,0) as 'new money'
FROM PRIZE 
ORDER BY event_id, place;
```

I can't figure out how to round x in the same statement - I guess the value hasn't been created yet?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just nest the function calls.

```
SELECT event_id, place, money, 
ROUND(POWER(money,2)/2,0) as 'new money'
FROM PRIZE 
ORDER BY event_id, place;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sub queries for this,

```
SELECT *, ROUND(x,0) as 'new money' 
FROM ( 
    SELECT *, POWER(money,2)/2 as x from PRIZE
) as TABLE1

ORDER BY event_id, place
```